# EditorGUILayout.TextField Not Changing/Working Unity 2017.1.1f1

Tags: c#, editor, unity-game-engine, inspector

**Issue** 
Using `EditorGUILayout.TextField` to edit the names of currencies allows me to modify the text within the field but does not modify the variable or save the changes I've made. Video shows what I mean if you don't understand:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fr3cA0_YhXM

**Code Not Working**:

```
for(int cnt = 0; cnt < Script.CurrencyLevels; cnt++)
{
    EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Currency " + cnt + ": ");
    Script.CurrencyName[cnt] = EditorGUILayout.TextField(Script.CurrencyName[cnt]);
}
```

**Full Code Links**

```
https://hastebin.com/omajulihor.cs
https://hastebin.com/eqefuvotog.cs
```

**Language: C#** 
**Engine: Unity 2017.1.1f1** 
 
*Thank you ahead of time for the help <3*

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First of all in ypur code you've a line a the beginning of the OnEditorGUI:

```
Script.CurrencyName = new string[Script.CurrencyLevels];
```

Which actually sets the `CurrencyName` no a *new empty array of a given size*, even if you don't change the size. And erases everything you are setting in this lines:

```
Script.CurrencyName[cnt] = EditorGUILayout.TextField(Script.CurrencyName[cnt]);
```

To fix this you should write some code to copy values from the 'old' array to the 'new' one.

Also, when you're changing some value inside you custom editor class you need to add two lines of code into the `OnInspectorGUI()` method, one at the beginning and the end:

```
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        //update the editor's representation of the object
        // which you're using the editor for
        serializedObject.Update();

        // Here goes your editor's custom logic

        //Save the changes you or editor's user has made to 
        // the target object
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
     }
```

For more information about `serializedObject` see the [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.html).

Comment: I added the two lines like you suggested, but I am still having the exact same issue. Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant. Here is the current code: https://hastebin.com/vexokemuki.cs
The other code remains the same. If possible could you provide me with an example?

Comment: @ShanePowell i found the error in your code and fixed my answer

Comment: Thank you very much, Worked like a charm and I'm back to work :D

Answer (score 0):

```
pathPattern= EditorGUILayout.TextField("pattern link ends with id.unity",pathPattern);
```

The problem is that on `void OnGUI()` is updating each frame
The solution is to override the default string